# CSS correct syntax for styling multiple descendant elements

Tags: css

lets say I have two different tables on my page and want style them separately. Also I want to define different styles for the descendant elements of each table separately.
Now the question arose how to write my css best. Even though the following is working in my browser (but not here in SO editor), I'm not sure if this is the correct way and should be used.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

table#table2 { 
  thead tr {
      font-size: 20px;
      background-color: red;
  }
  td{
      font-size: 10px;
      background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>Table1</h3>
    <table id="table1">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Last name</th>
              <th>First name</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Simpson</td>
              <td>Homer</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Simpson</td>
              <td>Marge</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <h3>Table2</h3>
    <table id="table2">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Fruit</th>
              <th>Size</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Grape</td>
              <td>small</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>Melon</td>
              <td>large</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Or must I write it as such (working in SO editor):

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


table#table2 thead tr {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
table#table2 td {
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

What is the correct syntax for styling multiple elements inside a specific element without having to define the parent all the time?

Comment: [CSS Nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting) is a relatively new feature, and might not have full browser support yet.

Comment: The best thing to do is to use classes in your markup so you can target your styles better (instead of tags). You're already doing this with ids but using classes is more flexible.

Comment: So would you recommend to use sass instead if I want to use nesting?

Comment: You can look at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20nesting) to see if the browser support for CSS nesting is good enough for the browsers you would like to support to decide if you wanna use Sass or not.

Comment: @B4DschK4Pp SASS/SCSS, LESS or PostCSS are the best options if you want nesting though as they are CSS processors you have to bake them into your dev pipeline/workflow. Depending on your project this might actually be overkill so first I'd confirm that you actually need to use nesting VS a good class name approach. Nowadays I tend to do projects with pure CSS as it's always improving and can often be simpler in the long run.